# words function fails to count correctly the number of words

Tags: makefile

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions):

> '$(words TEXT)'
>
> Returns the number of words in TEXT.  Thus, the last word of TEXT
>     is '$(word $(words TEXT),TEXT)'.

In practice, for the Makefile:

```
define collection
foo
bar
baz
endef


number := $(words $(collection))


collection:
    echo '$(number) words in my collection'
```

And running, I get:

```
echo '1 words in my collection'
1 words in my collection
```

And I, for a minute, thought that we had there 3 words. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you have used multiple lines without explicitly ending them with `\` to tell `make` that they are all part of the same line. If you were to define your `collection` with

```
define collection
foo bar baz
endef
```

or

```
define collecton
foo \
bar \
baz
endef
```

Then the recipe `collection` would correctly output `3 words in my collection`. You may also want to add `@` before the `echo` command as this will suppress the output of the line `echo '1 words in my collection'` [[1]](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html#Echoing). `@` is commonly used before lines in `makefile`s when you don't want the specific commands make is running to be output. A `makefile` which produces your expected output with the `@` symbol is provided below for you.

```
define collection
foo bar baz
endef

number := $(words $(collection))

collection:
    @echo '$(number) words in my collection'
```

**EDIT:** @[MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901577/words-function-fails-to-count-correctly-the-number-of-words#comment51728714_31903939) is correct. It is the additional space that makes this *work* correctly. However, I would add to this that if you were to add a recipe like

```
print:
    @echo $collection
```

and providing you correctly appended a space after each word it would still fail with `make: bar: Command not found` unless you use either of the 2 solutions I've provided above, the single line declaration or using `\`.

Comment: This isn't really correct per se.  You don't need to add backslashes into `define` statements; they are designed to allow newlines.  The thing that "fixes" this is the extra space not the backslash; you could remove the backslash but keep the space and it would report 3 words.  The reason for this is that the `words` function uses the C function `isblank()` to separate words and this only considers spaces and tabs as separators, not newlines.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for the clarification, I didn't realise that about `define` as my testing with the `print` recipe shown above won't print out the 3 words unless either solution I provided was used.