# Make fails to process a multi-line shell function

Tags: makefile

After showing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901066/is-that-smart-interpretation-by-the-shell-function-or-is-it-overreaching), that Make is quick to remove new-lines from a shell-function argumnet.

I tried this makefile:

```
# The original lines of the command were too long
# and in-fact, that's why i split them into 2 lines.
# For simplicity, I replaced the lines with single-character words.

define cmd
rm
dir
endef


x := $(shell $(cmd))

all:
    @:
```

Running, I get:

```
make: rm
dir: Command not found
```

Does it mean, that Make passes the command "rm\ndir" (note the NL charachter in-between!)?

Because, that's certainly not what we see in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. If you put an extra space after `rm` you should see the output `rm: cannot remove ‘\ndir’: No such file or directory`. If however, as I have previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901577/words-function-fails-to-count-correctly-the-number-of-words/31903939#31903939), you use

```
define cmd
rm dir
endef
```

or

```
define cmd
rm \
dir
endef
```

It will execute `rm dir`.